# Powershell output english only on non english OS

Tags: windows, powershell, operating-system

Running this simple command to get the OSArchitecture:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture
```

Returns:

```
64-bit
```

If the system is installed in english. If the system is installed in Spanish, it would return:

```
64 bits
```

Is there any way to **force** powershell to return the english only variant even if the OS itself is not english?

Comment: Simply use `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem` ?

Comment: @wOxxOm it would work for this case in particular, but not for other commands that return a string, im looking for something generic for all commands that do return anything.

Comment: `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Locale 1033` maybe?

Comment: `-Locale` does not always work too, example: `netsh wlan show drivers -Locale 1033`